# AWS Personalize usage with 5 million items (750k item limit)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-personalize

According to the limits specified in [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/personalize/latest/dg/limits.html), there is a 750k item limit on AWS personalize which is not adjustable (so no service quota increase request is possible)

I have 5+ million items in my database, is there any workaround for me to use AWS Personalize? am I misinterpreting the limit? Should I pre-filter 80% of my database and just use the top 20% for AWS Personalize?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to pre filter the items. You can input the 5 million items; Personalize will decide which items to include in the training according to heuristics based on interactions against the items. New items (recently created but no interactions) and existing items which have recently been interacted with are given a higher preference for inclusion in the 750K items we include in model training. The recommendations received are constrained to this list of 750K items decided by Personalize.

Product Team, Amazon Personalize